# Multiple "init.default" entries in Git config

Tags: git, git-branch

I just got into learning Git, and I saw that I need to config the `git init` default branch's name (barely even know what it is yet).

So I type this:

```
git config --global init.default branch XXXX
```

(with `XXXX` being the default branch name)

For some reason I tried it multiple times with different names like "Main" and "MainBranch"...

But cannot find it, I tried to show it and could not. And when I check the `git config --global --list` I get what you can see in the screenshot. Multiple `init.default=branch` which I don't know what it even means.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. I suggest that you do not worry about changing the default branch name for now until you have more experience with Git.

Comment: "I saw that I need to config the git init default branch's name" - no, you do not need to.